# troubleshooting steps for site that requires refresh to load

Tags: jquery, css

How does one troubleshoot a site that loads sometimes, but then requires a reload at other times... sometimes it loads, sometimes it hangs and a refresh is required, sometimes more than once.

What would you do in this situation? I'm just looking for basic troubleshooting steps to start me going in the right direction. In the meantime I'll be poking around in Chrome's "Inspect Element" but if there's specific things I should look at first let me know.

Comment: i think you are after net tab in firebug for firefox and Network tab in chrome's and Safari's, which can show you time and loaded assets and requests. Good tool for troubleshooting.

Comment: OK. When I goto the Network tab, then refresh the site, it automatically switches to the Sources tab, where it points to a jquery plugin which begins with an IF statement: (if(!jQuery.easing.easeInQuad){jQuery.extend, etc. etc. etc. Am I to understand that plugins shouldn't start with IF?

Comment: It is possible to `step over` errors in sources tab. So skip the error. Also it is possible to keep previous page load information in net tab if you select `persist` there.